# How to get XY coordinates of a control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, controls, coordinates

```
Point relativePoint = myVisual.TransformToAncestor(rootVisual)
                              .Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

this code block is very useful but, I use MVVM therefore the code block is useless for me ?

I wanna to get X & Y without using rootVisual.

Thanks & Best Regards.

Comment: If you use MVVM, your ViewModel shouldn't care about the view, so why do you want to do this?

Comment: I wanna to draw a line between 2 controls via ViewModel.

Comment: It's not the ViewModel's job, you should do it in the view. The ViewModel should only trigger this action (using an event or a messenger/mediator for instance), not actually perform it. The view could subscribe to the event in code-behind to actually draw the line.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I understand your question right. You dont want use rootVisual at all or only access indirect over myVisual?

something like this:

```
var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(myVisual) as UIElement;
     Point relativePoint = myVisual.TransformToAncestor(parent)
                          .Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Window.Left gives you the x coordinate while window.Top gives you the Y coordinate